# fetching data from django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-database

I am a newbie with Django. I created a table using Django models and inserted an object using the python shell. When I access the object using object id on Django template, I get the result as "{{obj.id}}-{{obj.content}}" rather than the actual data values.

The views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from .models import Tweet


# Create your views here.
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World!<h1>")

def tweet_detail_view(request, tweet_id, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = Tweet.objects.get(id = tweet_id)
    except:
        raise Http404
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello {{obj.id}} - {{obj.content}}</h1>")
```

The models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Tweet(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

The urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from tweets import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_view),
    path('tweet/<int:tweet_id>', views.tweet_detail_view),
]
```

The Shell

```
(base) ankita@ankita-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~/dev/trydjango/tweetme$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from tweets.models import Tweet                                        

In [2]: obj = Tweet.objects.get(id = 1)                                        

In [3]: obj                                                                    
Out[3]: <Tweet: Tweet object (1)>

In [4]: obj.content                                                            
Out[4]: 'Hello World!'

In [5]: obj.id                                                                 
Out[5]: 1
```

The localhost page have only next text:

> ## Hello {{obj.id}} - {{obj.content}}

Answer (score 2):

If you create template to render your page, this task is quite simple to achieve. So, why don/t you create template and render it using render?

**hello_word.html**

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <h1>Hello {{obj.id}} - {{obj.content}}</h1>
    </html>
</body>
```

**views.py**

instead of HttpResponse:

```
return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {'obj': obj})
```

I would say that this is a regular Django way to render templates.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I'm still curious about why it wasn't working with "HttpResponse()"

Comment: To be honest I am not 100% sure, but I believe that HttpResponse() is a shortcut to make http response from the view without using templates. Variables in double paranthesis are  patterns that template processor is substituting with real data while it renders your template. I believe that there is no template involved while you render with HttpResponse().